# How do I add a margin to the left of the logo in a WP header

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I am using the Ashe theme on Wordpress, which places the logo on the header image of the site in the middle. I managed to move the logo to the left of the header, but it has no margin, so the edge of the logo is right on the edge of the site. I want to add a 15px margin to the left of the logo, but nothing seems to work.

I have the following additional css added:

> $custom_logo_defaults img{float:left;margin-top:20%;margin-left:15px}

> $custom_logo_defaults .site-title{margin-top:2%;margin-left:15px}

I have also tried changing the php code in the style sheets, but that also doesn’t seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have provided will not work as is. You need to add the correct CSS selectors.

The correct CSS would be:

```
.custom-logo-defaults img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

__

```
.custom-logo-defaults .site-title {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```